# Read properties file from Gitlab from spring project

Tags: java, spring, ssl, gitlab

this must be a very silly issue but I'm trying to read very basic information from my gitlab repository (my repo is private so I can't show you the exact URL).
I execute the following code:
(I published an example of the file in a public repo (https://github.com/ProgramDisciple/cube) just for this example, but in my case it must be PRIVATE and the real URL is something like (https://gitlab.com/ProgramDisciple/gitcube) but I can't post it here, sorry )

```
GitlabAPI gitLabApi=GitlabAPI.connect("https://gitlab.com/ProgramDisciple/cube", "API-Token");
String host=gitLabApi.getHost();//
            gitLabApi.getProject("cube", "prop"); //--> here comes my error
```

The problem is that when I try to contact with GITLAB I get always the same error again and again:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I followed this links:
[Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error/

[Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

http://rubenjgarcia.es/sslhandshakeexception-install-ssl-keystore/

http://www.elblogdeselo.com/web-services-en-java-y-axis-solucionar-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception

[Connect to gitlab using Java's Gitlab API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156768/connect-to-gitlab-using-javas-gitlab-api)

But they don't solve my issue. There must be something very easy that I'm forgetting.

I've also imported the certificate of gitlab, but I still get the same problem:

```
./keytool -import -alias "xrepocert" -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/security/cacerts" -file "C:/gitlabcerts/cert/gitlab.cer"
```

-------------- SOLUTION --------------------------

My walkaround was using a config-server to read these properties, I followed this link (https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-config-server) in order to get my properties read each time I start my service.

Comment: Aheum... are your using the `GitlabAPI` to access a `github` project?

Comment: OK, I see you've corrected that...

Comment: I am stuck with something similar. Did you manage to find a solution @MrPotatoServer